# Where to get Oracle and JobID?

Tags: blockchain, solidity

I am working on making a smart contract using Chainlink oracles, and I’ve run into this issue. I have an API call that I want to make, but I’m not sure which nodes/oracles I should call. They give some sample nodes, but if I understand the technology properly, I should be able to call my own nodes. Where can I find this information? I know it needs to return a bytes32.

```
Oracle = // TODO
JOB = // TODO  
function requestJoke() public
  {
    Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(JOB, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
    req.add("get", "https://sv443.net/jokeapi/v2/joke/Any");
    req.add("path", "joke");
    sendChainlinkRequestTo(ORACLE, req, ORACLE_PAYMENT);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a chainlink oracle request, you can use any oracle that has a job that can return a bytes32.

You can look for and find Oracle contract address and Job IDs on sites such as [market.link](https://market.link/). The other important thing to note is that each Ethereum network (mainnet, ropsten, kovan, etc) each have different ID and addresses. You'll also need to differentiate between a `GET` and a `POST` request, you can also see the [chainlink docs](https://docs.chain.link/docs/request-and-receive-data) for more information.

An easy one would be to use the Alpha Chain oracles.

```
// A get request for bytes32 on Ropsten
address ORACLE = 0xB36d3709e22F7c708348E225b20b13eA546E6D9c;
bytes32 JOBID = "de6ad2f87c6b42679777dc658a93705c";

// This JOBID returns a bytes32 object
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating this post, as [market.link](https://market.link/) has since been deprecated (and will eventually be migrated to Dune Analytics).

In the meantime, to find a oracle and job id, you'll need to join the Chainlink Official Discord server, and post your request to the **#operator-requests** channel.

You may also feel free to browse our oracle jobs and ids, all of which are posted [here](https://docs.linkwellnodes.io/services/direct-request-jobs/mainnets) (disclaimer: Chainlink community node operator here).

Hope that helps!